# In Vim, can I move a line to current line without leaving the current line?

Tags: vim, vi

The title says it all: is there a way in Vi(m) to move a line, by number, to my current line?

I could move to my source line first, then use the `:m` command to move that line. But that involves leaving my target line. Or, I could `:Nd`, but that also moves me off of my current line and on to the deleted line number `N`.

It's frustrating looking at a line and thinking "move here" and not knowing how :D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:3m .` moves line 3 to your current line.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Didn't know about `.` as an address. Do you know where in `:help` I read more about that? I checked `:help move`...

Comment: Well, actually, guess I should read http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down